# " jointly proportional to $r$ and $h$" versus "directly proportional to both $r$ and $h$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology, article-writing

Which of these statements correctly describe the formula $S = 2\pi rh$ ?

1. $S$ is jointly proportional to $r$ and $h$
2. $S$ is directly proportional to $r$ and $h$
3. $S$ varies directly with $r$ and $h.$

I am leaning towards choice 3, but am not sure.

This stuff on variation that might help ($k$ is a constant):

> "S varies as x" means S = kx
>
> "S varies jointly as x and y" means S = kxy
>
> "S varies as x + y" means S = k(x + y)
>
> "S varies inversely as x" means S = k/x.

Comment: How are the adverbs "jointly" and "directly" defined in your book?

Comment: I think directly means a constant is being multiplied with 1 variable, jointly means a constant is being multiplied with more than 1 variable. see edit.

Comment: So, why did you choose the third as opposed to, say, the first?

Comment: Ah, because I didn't realize 2pi(r) wasn't a constant. 2pi would be k and radius and height would be variables so thinking about it that way, the first choice seems best.

Comment: I would go with the first choice as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would use all three of those sentences to describe the relationship in question. I don't really see why your book is teaching you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "describe" in the question is in the plural. That would seem to imply that any number of answers can be selected. As Chris noted in the comments, all three sentences are OK (assuming an appropriate definition of the terms used).

Answer (score 0):

> Which of these statements correctly describe the formula $S = 2\pi rh$ ?

> 1. $S$ is **jointly proportional to $r$ and $h$**

This option ($S\propto rh$) *directly* describes the above formula, so is always correct.

> 2. $S$ is **directly proportional to $r$ and $h$**
> 3. $S$ **varies directly with $r$ and $h$**

These options ($S\propto r \quad\text{and}\quad S\propto h$) would be wrong [**if**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4323252/21813) $r$ depends on $h.$

For example, the constraint $$h=3r$$ implies that $$6\pi r^2=S=\frac23\pi h^2,$$ which implies that $S$ is proportional neither to $r$ nor to $h.$